# Jquery slidedown one element in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I have a div like this:

```
<div>
  <font class='slideclick'>Click here to slidedown dynamic content</font>
  <div class='slidedownonclick'> This is the content that slides down </div>
</div>
```

Jquery triggers the 'slidedownonclick' to slidedown when 'slideclick' is clicked. This works great but i have and indefinite amount on these div's reccuring in the same webpage, from a mysql database. Giving them unique id's is impossible. Is there any way that i could get only the 'slidedownonclick' in the same div as its respective 'slideclick' to slidedown when it is clicked.

Any help would be much appreciated,

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

On a `.slideclick` handler you will find that sibling with:

```
$(this).find('+ .slidedownonclick');
```

or:

```
$(this).next('.slidedownonclick');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will slide down the next `.slidedownonclick` div when `.slideclick` is clicked:

```
$('.slideclick').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.slidedownonclick').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: It not working for me, what version of jquery is this using??

Comment: This should work with any reasonably recent version of jQuery. Are these elements added dynamically? Is `.slidedownonclick` the next child of `.slideclick`, or are there elements in between?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slideclick').click(function() {
 $(this).next('.slidedownonclick').animate({
    height: '+=50'
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check about [jQuery.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), it's what do you want.
Using it you can get the next sibbling which class/id is the selector.
**EDITED:**
**until jQuery 1.6.4**

```
   jQuery(document).delegate('font.slideclick', 'click', function() {
        jQuery(this).next('slidedownonclick').slideToggle();
    });
```

**jQuery 1.7 +**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'font.slideclick', function() {
    jQuery(this).next('slidedownonclick').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Should probably use native `.click()` or `.on()`.

Comment: It depends what jquery version he's using.

Comment: Correct, but even so, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) states: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`